# How to layout this overlapping typo using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am currently working on this layout that is shown in this Sketch artboard.[image]

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I am not sure if this is possible to achieve. I like to align the green box to the responsive bootstrap grid that adopts to the different viewports. And at the same time the Typo should be laid on top using also the bootstrap grid system.

Does somebody have a clue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried flexboxes? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37491/

You want like this? It also works in responsive.
Just give negative margin-left to your text inside green box.
Dont forget to leave some space for your title, do not take full width for green box.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="feature" class="row">
        <div class="pull-right bg-green">
            <h2>Featured Project</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lookbook</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#feature {
    padding: 100px 0 0 100px;
}
#feature h2, #feature p{
    margin-left:-100px;
}
.bg-green {
    background: green;
    padding:40px;
    width:90%;
    height:500px;
}
```